# make prestashop store in a django subdomain

Tags: python, django, prestashop, subdomain, cpanel

good afternoon everyone, I have my website made with django (python app), hosted in the domain [www.cannareis.com.ar](http://www.cannareis.com.ar).
but I want to add a virtual store using prestashop. Thanks to my hosting provider, I can download prestashop directly from the Cpanel of my website.
Since I already have my page made with django, I don't want or can't put my page made with prestashop in the same domain, so I created a subdomain called [www.tienda.cannareis.com.ar](http://www.tienda.cannareis.com.ar).
but when I want my prestashop to be hosted there, it doesn't let me and the first thing that appears when I enter is the django error message, asking me to put the domain in allowed hosts. I don't understand why the django message appears if I'm on a subdomain, I'm not on the original domain where I put my django app.
I tried to register the subdomain in allowed hosts (settings.py) but when I do that, when I enter the subdomain [www.tienda.cannareis.com.ar](http://www.tienda.cannareis.com.ar) , the main template of my web page appears, that is, the "home". and to access the prestashop page I have to add /es to the url. that is to say, it remains [www.tienda.cannareis.com.ar/es/](http://www.tienda.cannareis.com.ar/es/)

or putting anything after the / takes me to the prestashop page, but I want my prestashop project to appear as soon as [www.tienda.cannareis.com.ar](http://www.tienda.cannareis.com.ar) is written, but my django project overlaps that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it has nothing to do with PrestaShop and is related to how your server is configured. Your subdomain should point to the directory where your PrestaShop files are available. Probably, it is not the case right now. I would recommend asking the hosting provider how to deal with it.

Comment: Genial, gracias.